# How to save and read files from storage using flutter on android 11 and above?

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I built an app using Flutter that converts files from type to another (e.g., txt to pdf).

It has to:

1. get directory path that user can choose to save converted files to,
2. read file/files to convert and
3. save the file/files that converted by the app to the directory.

Actually I can do that using the permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. My question is if I can do this without using this permission, because I tried to upload it to google play but unfortunately my request was rejected because my app is using this permission.

**I don't prefer using kotlin or java code to do this.**

I appreciate any response.

Comment: `get directory path that user can choose to save converted files to,` How would you get that parh using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: `read file/files to convert ` How would the user choose such files using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: `don't prefer using kotlin or java code to do this.` Them wich language?

Comment: try these permissions instead of manage_external_storage
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @blackapps for questions 1 and 2: I just asked the user to allow the app to access all files and I just used FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath() and FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(...) to do it. 

I didn't understand your 3d question. But if you ask me wich language I want to use, my answer is Dart (flutter).

Comment: @Piotr thanks for your answer .. actually I'm already using these permissions but they didn't work on Android 13+.

Comment: Starting in Android 11, apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage. To access the directory that the system provides for your app.

Please consult
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13

However you can use downloads folder as far as I know
https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files